# I am learning python and got stuck on this problem. When the number is palindrome instead of returning True the code returns None

Tags: python, python-3.x

When the number is palindrome instead of returning True the code returns None.

```
def is_palindrome(n):
    string = str(n)
    length = len(string)

    if length%2 == 0:
        for k in range(0, int(length/2)):
            if string[k] == string[length-k-1]:
                continue
                return True
            else:
                return False

    if length%2 != 0:
        for k in range(0, int(length/2)):
            if string[k] == string[length-k-1]:
                continue
                return True
            else:
                return False

print(is_palindrome(1221))
```

Comment: `return True` is never reached because of the `continue`. You also probably want to `return True` at the end of the loop if you haven't already returned `False`.

Comment: What is `continue; return True` supposed to mean? `continue` immediately jumps to the beginning of the innermost loop, and control never reaches `return True`

Comment: Learn to use a debugger: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see how you're trying to do it, and I don't know if you want me to keep the methodology of your solution, but here is a simpler way that you can solve this problem.

```
def pal(x):
    if str(x) == (str(x)[::-1]):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This function just checks if the number given is the same reversed. Hope this helps. With your method, the problem probably has to do with your use of 'continue', which I personally don't use much although I know it could prove to be quite useful.

Comment: Even shorter: `return str(x) == str(x)[::-1]`

Comment: Thank you for your help, this makes my code so much easy

Comment: @Matthias Wow, I can't believe I missed that, thank you for the upgrade.